# Gradle make multiple war with different resources and classes

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java web project, and I use Gradle to build project, the project structure as follow.

I want use Gradle to build 2 wars, main.war and api.war, and the wars structure as follow.

I have try many times to build these 2 wars, but when main.war is correct the api.war is wrong, when api.war is correct the main.war is wrong.

Could anyone give me some helps? Thanks.

project structure:

```
project-root
  |--src
    |--api
      |--resources
        |--api.xml
      |--webapp
        |--WEB-INF
          |--web.xml(api)
    |--main
      |--java
         |--xxx.xxx.api
         |--xxx.xxx.model
         |--some other packages
      |--resources
        |--main.xml
      |--webapp
        |--websrc
          |--js
          |--style
        |--WEB-INF
          |--web.xml(main)
        |--index.html
```

The wars structure I want:

```
main.war
  |--websrc
    |--js
    |--style
  |--WEB-INF
    |--classes
      |--all packages exclude api package
      |--main.xml
    |--web.xml(main)
  |--index.html



api.war
  |--WEB-INF
    |--classes
      |--xxx.xxx.api
      |--xxx.xxx.model
      |--api.xml
    |--web.xml(api)
```

My gradle file:

```
task create_main_war(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = "main"
    rootSpec.exclude("**/api/**") 
}

task create_api_war(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = "api"
    SourceSets {
        main.resources.srcDirs += "src/api/resources"
    }
    webAppDirName = "src/api/webapp
    rootSpec.exclude("**/main.xml")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/someOtherPackages/**") 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the *build.gradle* file you are using so we have a starting point?

Comment: ok, I have added my gradle file content already.

Comment: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, ok, I'll close the question and focus on the  [forums.gradle.org](http://forums.gradle.org/) question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close, please view the forums.gradle.org question : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-make-multiple-war-with-different-resources-and-classes/6705