# how to make multiple war artifacts with gradle source sets

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am trying to convert an existing gradle project to use source sets so that I can reuse some classes in two separate applications.

I have the following new build.gradle thus far:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
        classpath('com.h2database:h2:1.4.193')
        classpath('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.1.Final')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets{
    main{
        apply plugin: 'idea'
        java{
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
    api{
        apply plugin: 'idea'
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'war'
        springBoot{
            mainClass="com.robocubs4205.cubscout.Application"
        }
        java{
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/api/java']
        }
        war{
            baseName="cubscout-server"
            version="0.0.0"
        }

    }
    web_client{
        apply plugin: 'idea'
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'war'
        springBoot{
            mainClass="com.robocubs4205.cubscout.Application"
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/web-client/java', 'src/main/java']
        }
        war{
            baseName="cubscout-client"
            version="0.0.0"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.2.RELEASE'
    //compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE'
    //compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.23.0.RELEASE'
    //compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.7.RELEASE'
    //compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.6.0.RELEASE'
    //compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.1.Final'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.193'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.1.RELEASE'
}
```

My intent is to create two artifacts: `cubscout-client-0.0.0.war` and `cubscout-server-0.0.0.war`, with the former using the source in `src/web-client`, the latter using the source in `src/api`, and both using the source form `src/main`. However, It only creates one at a time.

the closest I could find to an answer was [Gradle make multiple war with different resources and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285296/gradle-make-multiple-war-with-different-resources-and-classes), but I could not understand the answer because, as with the majority of writing on Gradle I have read, people don't give any context to where in build.gradle their snippets go.

I am using Intellij Idea as my IDE, and help getting these two artifacts to be visible to Intellij would also be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have tried using a multi-project build instead of using source sets. The build.gradle is as folllows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath('com.h2database:h2:1.4.193')
        classpath('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.1.Final')
    }
}
plugins{
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

allprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.2.RELEASE'
        //compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE'
        //compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.23.0.RELEASE'
        //compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.7.RELEASE'
        //compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.7.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.0.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.6.0.RELEASE'
        //compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.1.Final'
        compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.193'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
        providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.1.RELEASE'
    }
}

project(':api'){
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    springBoot{
        mainClass="com.robocubs4205.cubscout.Application"
    }
    war{
        baseName="cubscout-server"
        version="0.0.0"
    }
    dependencies{
        compile project(':')
    }
}

project(':web-client'){
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    springBoot{
        mainClass="com.robocubs4205.cubscout.Application"
    }
    war{
        baseName="cubscout-client"
        version="0.0.0"
    }
    dependencies{
        compile project(':')
    }
}
```

When I `api:build` or `client:build`, the build succeeds, but running `build` causes springs `bootRepackage` task to fail with `Unable to find main class`. Further, the artifacts from `api:build` and `client:build` do not seem to have spring-boot enabled, as they do not have any console output from spring when it normally has several pages.

Comment: Why don't you split it into separate projects?

Comment: @opal I don't know how to do that. The documentation I could find was confusing and seemed to imply separate projects didn't share sources.